# How to continue with the next file if one fails in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a main ansible playbook site.yml which includes three books one for webservers, one for dbservers, one for others.
Each has their own selection crietia specified in their own files e.g hosts:tag_name_webapp1 and similar. The issue is, if all hosts in web servers fail, ansible stops execution then and there. I want it to continue with the tasks in dbservers and so on.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands?

Comment: Yes, but that has to be applied to each task. I wanted something for included files.

Comment: Provide a tag to each role and use --tags to include the roles that you want to provision, in case you know that one will fail for certain just don't include it or use --skip-tags to skip it (i.e `ansible-playbook site.yml --skip-tags "webservers"`)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue on to the next task after one fails, you can use `ignore_errors`.

https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that, but putting that for every task is too much work specially when each file has numerous roles and other included files. I was hoping there was a workaround to it.